# How to point a custom sub-domain to a sub-directory of a Github repository

Tags: git, github

Say I have custom subdomain `x.site.com`, configured it via my DNS provider to point to one of my Github repos, say `repo`. What `x.site.com` is pointing to - now - is the root of the repo where `CNAME`  file exists containing `x.site.com`. My question, How to make that subdomain points to a subdirectory say `repo/docs` and not to the root of the repo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step #1**

Push the target sub-directory to `gh-pages` branch via the next command:

```
git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages
```

**Step #2**

Include `CNAME` file in the target sub-directory containing `x.site.com`.

**Notes**

- Make sure that target sub-directory **isn't included in `.gitignore`** file and also **committed**.
- Make sure to replace `dist` in the previous command with your sub-directory name (e.g. `build`, `public`).
- Each time you make a change you have to repeat the previous command.

For more details about the process and how to automate it and sync between the `master` branch and `gh-pages` branch, [**view this gist**](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490)